# Overwrite remote repo with local

Tags: git

I currently have a local repo `temp3` that was created by running `git svn clone`.  Someone else has created a remote repository called `SS`.  The two are not related (from a git perspective), however, they are both generated from the same SVN repo (at different points of time).  I would like to overwrite `SS` with `temp3` on the remote server.  Is this possible?  Below is what I tried

```
git push -f -v --repo=address
```

It came back with an error

```
The current branch master has no upstream branch
```

Then it said to use `--set-upstream` instead of `--repo` and `-f`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The manual says there's a `git push --mirror`, does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

try this

> git push -f remote_address

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the remote of your second repo

```
git remote add <repo2> <url>
```

Once you have multiple remotes you can push to any of the give remotes.

```
git push -f repo1 master
git push -f repo2 <branch>
```